# Sort in bash not sorting csv strings properly

Tags: bash, shell, sorting

So my program reads in a csv and sorts the rows based on a field. It does this first sort fine. The issue is later when I need to sort it based off another field the function I've written seems to sort it about halfway, then quit sorting. This is what my function looks like:

```
function sortByField() {
    local fieldId=$((`indexOf $1` + 1 )) #indexOf returns an int representing a zero based index
    tmp=`for x in ${_records[@]}; do echo $x; done | sort -t$DELIMITER -k$fieldId,${fieldId}n`
    _records=$tmp
}
```

After sorting using this method, if I echo out all the values from _records, it has double the amount of entries, the first half sorted by the new field, the second sorted the way I'd originally done it. Oddly enough, outputting the amount of items in the array (via `echo ${#_records[@]}`) returns the same number, before and after sorting and ending up with duplicates.

How do I just sort this array, without getting all the duplicate results?

I realize this may be an easy question, but this is for school and I'm by no means experienced with scripting in bash. I tried searching the site but couldn't find anything that referenced my problem.

EDIT: For those interested, here's how the records are initially passed into `_records`:

```
#after creating an array t containing all the csv fields, translate it back to string format with the additional fields
_records[$i]=`echo "${t[@]} $vprio $remTime $START_TIME_DEFAULT | tr ' ' ','"`
```

Comment: You're taking a course and have to write a program in Bash?  That is interesting.  What kind of course is it?

Comment: `_records` is not an array (at least, not after you call `sortByField` the first time), because `tmp` is not an array. Both are single strings containing a series of words separated by newlines.

Comment: If your instructor is telling you to use backquotes instead of `$(...)`, you should probably drop the course now.

Comment: @asawley it's a computer science OS course. We're using bash code to simulate context switches.

Comment: @chepner ah ok, then how would I sort the array without turning it into a string? And I realize I can use both, I just prefer backticks for readability.

Comment: If you think backticks are more readable than `$()`, you lack experience using backticks.

Comment: I do, if you read above you'd see I'm learning how to code in bash. Can I get an answer for the question or are we all gonna continue to question my arbitrary choice of backticks over `$()`?

Comment: How is `_records` set in the first place?

Comment: why do you think `sort` without `-u` option should eliminate duplicates?

Comment: @chepner I will add it in an edit above because it's a bit large for a comment

Comment: @karafka it shouldn't be creating duplicates to begin with, the fact that duplicates are incurred is a bug

Comment: What is in `_records`, is `IFS` the default `" \t\n"`, what does `${_records[@]}` expand to? Should it be quoted to prevent *word-splitting*? (e.g. `"${_records[@]}"'`)

Comment: IFS is the default, I don't touch it. I have no idea what you mean by expanding and word splitting isn't an issue, there's not a single white space character in the csv (nor is there a risk of one, teacher's guarantee) beyond the newlines.

Comment: perhaps you meant `_records[$i]=$(echo "${t[@]} $vprio $remTime $START_TIME_DEFAULT" | tr ' ' ',')` ??  **Note:** the changes to **double-quotes**...  Also note, for *indexed* arrays in bash there is no need for the `$` before the index variable (e.g. `_records[i]` is fine)

Answer (score 0):

Use `sort` to do all the sub-sorting in one pass, (with the original *.CSV* file as input), *then* load the sorted results into an array.  The syntax of `sort` can be confusing, here's an example:

```
# a random-ish grid.
cat /tmp/baz
4,c,3,d
1,a,3,c
2,b,2,d
1,b,4,a
# sort field #1 in reverse numeric order, and where possible, field #4 alphabeticly
sort -t, -k1gr,1 -k4,4 /tmp/baz
4,c,3,d
2,b,2,d
1,b,4,a
1,a,3,c
```